# Tomcat Installation using binaries- endorsed is not supported & error: could not create the JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jvm-arguments, catalina

I ve tried to install Tomcat server using binary files in eclipse.When I run cmd and run the startup command, cmd opens and closes and these written on the cmd screen:

> ```
> >startup
> ```

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

(startup.bat also tried but behaves same)

- When I run this command:

  > catalina.bat run

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

```
>java -version
```

> java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19 
>  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 15.0.2+7-27) 
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

```
>javac -version
```

> javac 15.0.2

- In the project, JRE setting is like that:

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Library -> **JavaSE-1.8**

- Eclipse version is :

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

```
>echo %CATALINA_HOME%
```

> C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.69

```
>echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

%CATALINA_HOME%\bin exists in Path variable.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

Comment: Does running tomcat with java 8 or using a newer tomcat version work?

Comment: Check if you don't have a `JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS` environment variable or an `endorsed` folder in your Tomcat installation.

Comment: @dan1st yes, I tried installation with tomcat 8.5.69 and  9.0 but not works, also  I am not able to use jdk 8 because my Eclipse version generate issues

Comment: Then why not try with the current Eclipse version?

Answer (score 2):

From [catalina.bat source code](https://fossies.org/linux/apache-tomcat/bin/catalina.bat).

```
  234 rem Java 9 no longer supports the java.endorsed.dirs
  235 rem system property. Only try to use it if
  236 rem JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS was explicitly set
  237 rem or CATALINA_HOME/endorsed exists.
  238 set ENDORSED_PROP=ignore.endorsed.dirs
  239 if "%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" == "" goto noEndorsedVar
  240 set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
  241 goto doneEndorsed
  242 :noEndorsedVar
  243 if not exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" goto doneEndorsed
  244 set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
  245 :doneEndorsed
```

Also, from the error message it can be seen that the property was passed on tomcat start command line:  `-Djava.endorsed.dirs= ...` so either `JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS` env var exists or `CATALINA_HOME/endorsed` directory exists.

Comment: One of the tomcat has endorsed file, and I made changes on settings file. I uninstalled all old versions of Tomcat and install Tomcat 8.5.69 , now  [http://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) , tomcat web page appears.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you :-)